# how to search for built-in methods in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

could you advise how to search for built-in methods in laravel? For example I want to find controller's method validate() provided by the Illuminate\Http\Request and see how it works

Comment: Do you want to see the method interface with parameters, default parameters and return value? Or do you want to see the implementation of the methods?

Comment: Hello, I think both  implementation and parameters & return

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use IDEs (for example, PhpStorm) that provide such features. Look for "Go to declaration/definition" commands for the IDE you are using.
- If you don't use IDE that supports jumps like that you can use external tools (I personally use [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)) to index your project's folder and generate tags file for all the classes, methods etc. But this approach will require additional setup from your part.
- You can use debugger to trace your code in real time. But it requires for PHP debugger (like `xdebug`) to be set up and an IDE that supports debugging.
- Lastly you can search for classes or methods you are interested in yourself. Laravel utilizes PSR-4 for autoloading, so the namespace of any class can easily lead you to the correct file inside `/vendor/laravel/framework/src`.

Comment: Hello, I tried 'go for definition' in phpstorm but in my case it searches for required method only in one level up parent class, and if it has multilevel inheritance phpstorm can't find the definition.